# SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1305

Tags: database, fuelphp

I've been using FuelPHP to develop a new web application.
Today, all of a sudden, errors started appearing when I try to add information to the database.

I can still retrieve information from the database so the login information must be correct. However when I try to add info I'm getting the following error message:

> Error - 2012-08-06 15:48:37 --> Error - SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1305 FUNCTION dan_monline.LOWER does not exist with query: "SELECT LOWER (`name`) FROM `countries` WHERE `name` = 'costa rica'" in /home/danlucas/public_html/portfolio-dir/music-online/fuel/core/classes/database/pdo/connection.php on line 167

I'm not sure if this is a FuelPHP specific error or if it is MySQL that is causing the problem. From what I understand it's saying that 'LOWER' doesn't exist?

Has anyone seen this error before or know how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed the problem by updating the mysql software.

Answer (score 2):

Try again to remove the space after 'LOWER'.

--
SELECT LOWER(...