# php fuel 42000 error

Tags: php, fuelphp

I don't get what's wrong. This is the full error I get:

```
Fuel\Core\Database_Exception [ 42000 ]: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation:
1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL 
server version for the right syntax to use near 'to, from, message, checked) VALUES ('1', 
'freddy', 'bob', 'message', '1')' at line 1 with query: "INSERT INTO chatmes (id, to, from, 
message, checked) VALUES ('1', 'freddy', 'bob', 'message', '1')"
```

And this my PHP code which is supposedly giving me the error:

```
<?php

define('DOCROOT', __DIR__.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);                 
define('APPPATH', realpath('/var/www/vhosts/grubber.co.nz/httpdocs/fuel/app/').DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
define('PKGPATH', realpath('/var/www/vhosts/grubber.co.nz/httpdocs/fuel/packages/').DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
define('COREPATH', realpath('/var/www/vhosts/grubber.co.nz/httpdocs/fuel/core/').DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);                  
require APPPATH.'bootstrap.php';

error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$to = $_GET['to'];
$from = $_GET['from'];
$message = $_GET['message'];


$dquotes = '"';
$squotes = "'";

$message = str_replace($dquotes, "&quot", $message);
$message = str_replace($squotes, "&#039", $message);

DB::insert('chatmes')->set(array('id' => '1', 'to' => 'freddy', 'from' => 'bob', 'message' => 'message', 'checked' => '1'))->execute();

?>
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong. Also the connection I'm using is **PDO**.

At the moment the only line thats giving me a error is the DB update query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out, it had nothing to do with my query, it was fuelphp. It didn't like the database `from` to `sender` and `to` to `receiver`.
Thanks guys for helping.

Answer (score 1):

try putting a semicolon at the end like this,

changer your DB::insert query creator

```
 INSERT INTO chatmes (id, to, from, 
     message, checked) VALUES ('1', 'freddy', 'bob', 'message', '1');"
```

Comment: yer I changed my DB::insert into DB::query, it still gives me a error

Comment: Hey it's your mysql server issue check phpfuel document they must have solution for this issue. Because some mysql server has this problem though they have solution for this. Else you try to update your mysql server. http://fuelphp.com/forums/discussion/6424 / http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11833122/sqlstate42000-syntax-error-or-access-violation-1305-solved